# find child table selector from parent table - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table structure like this. Fairly simple one.

```
  <table id="myTable" class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

At runtime I am binding a new row to this table for a particular `rowclick`. This new row contains a new table.

Now on clicking the row again, I want to be able to remove the newly added `row(the new table)`.

I am using `bootstrap table`.

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
$('#myTable').on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {
    //if ($element.has('#newlyAddedTable').length) { ....// did not work

    if ($('#myTable').has('#newlyAddedTable').length) {  // this removes the table on any row click. Not what I intend to do
    {
        $("#newlyAddedTable").remove();
    } else {
        // some operation...
    }
}
```

I want to be able to remove the newly added table on the row it was created.

Just more explanation based on the Answers below:

```
<tr> ----------> if i click this
  <td>
    <table id="newlyAddedTable"> ---------> this is added
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr> ----------> if i again click this or maybe any other row in the table
  <td>
    <table id="newlyAddedTable"> ---------> this is removed
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please do not use an id selector for the new table; once two new tables are added, your HTML becomes invalid and you cannot predict how the browser would handle any manipulation with regards to that repeated id.

Comment: @peterka, makes sense....i actually had a lot of `bootstrap` classes written on the table and hence thought of ID selector

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**: from OP's comment below it sounds like the best way to implement the new table is to use a class selector and not an id selector. The code below has been updated accordingly. ***Where previously there was an id for `newTable` there is a class ---> `#newTable` ===> `.newTable`:

Just change:

```
$('#myTable').has('#newlyAddedTable').length
```

To:

```
$('.newlyAddedTable', $element).length  //element === clicked row -- see demo
```

**vvvvv DEMO vvvvv**

```js
$('#myTable').bootstrapTable().on('click-row.bs.table', function(e, row, $element) {
    if( $('.newTable', $element).length ) {
        $('.newTable', $element).remove();
    } else {
        $('td:first', $element)
        .append( '<table class="newTable"><tr><td>NEW TABLE</td></tr></table>' );
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.7.0/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.7.0/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="myTable" class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: See the comment: `// this removes the table on any row click. Not what I intend to do`

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you have multiple tables with the same ID? That would invalidate your HTML and browser behavior would not be consistent. If a click should insert a table any clicked row then use a class for the new table. Please see my update above -- shortly.

Comment: @PeterKA, if a click inserts a table on a row click then it should remove the same table on the same row click or any other row click. More like the accordion feature.

Comment: Can the `NEW TABLE` be removed on a different row click as well. Just like how accordion works.

Comment: Do you want all new tables to be removed by clicking any row?

Comment: *Not really sure why someone would downvote this ...*

Comment: First click - one row created
Second click - it can be on the same first row or any other row, either ways remove the first row created and add a new row for the second click
Third click and so on....

Comment: @PeterKA, yours is definitely the answer i am looking for

Comment: So how come I don't understand your new requirement? Are you now removing rows and not the new table?

Comment: @PeterKA, the demo above is 90% of what is required. currently the newly added row(which is a table) can only be removed if it is again clicked on that same row. I am asking, can it be removed on any other row click as well. much like how accordion works.

Comment: Yes, it can; you just have to provide the right logic to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing your remove code with this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#newlyAddedTable", function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

The code above registers a click listener on the `document`. The second parameter filters those events for those with the target `#newlyAddedTable`. This way you don't have to register a new click handler every time you insert a row (as in @VimalanJayaGanesh's solution).

**P.S.** If you are adding HTML that looks like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <table id="newlyAddedTable">
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Then you are probably actually wanting to remove the parent `tr` (not the table with the `id`). There are two ways to fix this.

1. You can change the selector that filters click events and so have the `tr` handle the click rather than the `table` element in my example code:

`$(document).on("click", "tr:has(#newlyAddedTable)", function(){`

2. You can leave the selector as is but grab the parent `tr` from the table and remove that changing the remove line above to:

`$(this).parents("tr").first().remove()`

or

`$(this).parent().parent().remove()`

Comment: are you asking me to remove this from my code and replace with yours - `$('#myTable').on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {`

Comment: @NitinP sorry - wrong timezone to help but I see you are sorted.

Answer (score 3):

As I don't have your complete code / fiddler, here is a possible solution.

Are you looking for something like this?

```js
$('#add').on('click', function()
  {
     var newRow = '<tr CLASS="newrow"><td colspan="3"><table><tr><td>Test</td><td>User</td><td>test@example.com</td></table></td></tr>'
     $('#myTableBody').append(newRow); 
  Remove()
  });

function Remove()
{
 $('.newrow').off('click').on('click', function()
    {  
        $(this).remove();
    });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="myTableBody">
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
<button type='button' id='add'>Add</button>
```

Note:

The following line indicates that,

```
$('.newrow').off('click').on('click', function()
```

the click event will be binded to the new row only once.

The reason for adding 'off('click') is, when you are dynamically adding rows (with common class 'newrow') to the table, the events will be binded several times. To avoid that, remove the previously binded click event and add a new one.

Comment: can you please explain in your answer what does this do - `$('.newrow').off('click').on('click', function()`

Comment: so should i remove - `$('#myTable').on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {` or will your code - `$('.newrow').off('click').on('click', function()` be inside of the click event that i am using